# Render escaped html in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm pulling product descriptions from Amazon and they arrive escaped, looking like `&lt;i&gt;New York Times&lt;/i&gt;`

When I use h, raw or html_safe it shows up in my application as  <i>New York Times</i>

But I'd really like it to show up as *New York Times*

Comment: So it shows the brackets when using `html_safe`? Maybe use `html_safe` twice?

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if that worked? Sadly no combination of h/raw/html_safe seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= CGI.unescapeHTML("&lt;i&gt;New York Times&lt;/i&gt;").html_safe %>
```

The issue is that the string contains html that has already been escaped.  So, you need to 'unesacpe' it first.

Comment: Great! I looked through the CGI documentation because I thought I remembered this kind of thing being in there, but I must have overlooked this. Thanks!